Apm-server elasticsearch Kibana docker-compose Springboot 3.2.0
The aim : The APM agent server collects metrics and traces from the running application. The APM server processes the data received from the APM agent (metrics) and sends it to Elasticsearch for storage. Visualization with the web user interface for Elasticsearch is done through Kibana, which allows visualization and analysis of the data stored in Elasticsearch.  I added in
my pom.xml: `<dependency>             <groupId>co.elastic.apm</groupId>             <artifactId>elastic-apm-agent</artifactId>             <version>1.49.0</version>         </dependency> `
application.yml: `elastic:     apm:         server_url: http://localhost:8200`   `
apm-server.yml: apm-server:     host: "apm-server:8200"     rum:         enabled: true     ilm:         enabled: false output.elasticsearch:     hosts: [ "http://elasticsearch:9200" ]     ssl.verification_mode: none setup.kibana:     host: "kibana:5601" `
docker-compose.yml: `version: '3.7'  services:     apm-server:         image: docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:8.13.2         container_name: apm-server         ports:             - "8200:8200"         environment:             - output.elasticsearch.hosts=["elasticsearch:9200"]         depends_on:             - elasticsearch             - kibana         volumes:             - ./apm-server.yml:/apm-server.yml         networks:             - apm-network      elasticsearch:         image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.13.2         container_name: elasticsearch         environment:             - discovery.type=single-node         ports:             - "9200:9200"         networks:             - apm-network      kibana:         image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.13.2         container_name: kibana         ports:             - "5601:5601"         depends_on:             - elasticsearch         environment:             - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200         networks:             - apm-network  networks:     apm-network:         driver: bridge `
I have this error on my apm-server:
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T09:33:35.638Z","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/agentcfg.(\*ElasticsearchFetcher).Run.func1","file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go","file.line":150},"message":"refresh cache error: context deadline exceeded","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}

2024-04-17T09:33:37.076779379Z {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T09:33:37.076Z","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater.waitReady","file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.line":64},"message":"precondition failed: EOF","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}

2024-04-17T09:33:53.463311744Z 

when i Configure Elastic to get started i add adress http://elasticsearch:9200 i have Couldn't connect to cluster  Check the address and retry.

The number of files posted is adequate. It's a good idea to put files and code excerpts in pre-formatted text-blocks (code-blocks in the tool-bar). That can be useful to preserve white-space in the files or for you to add white-space to improve readability.
